# How to reuse SBT module project definitions

Tags: scala, code-reuse, sbt

How can I share the definition of a [Simple Build Tool](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/) *module* project
between many *parent* projects?
and at the same time
  include the module project definition in each parent project build file?

Clarification:

I have a parent project, and a *Dao* module project and a *App* module project and a *Core* project. Both module projects (i.e. *Dao* and *App*) depend on (the exact same version of) *Core*:

```
Parent project
  |
  |--> app
  |     `--> core
  |
  `--> dao
        `--> core
```

I defined *App*, *Dao* and *Core* in their own project directories, ([as described here](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/SubProjects#Build_Definitions_in_Subprojects))
so they can be resued by many parent projects.
However, when I load the parent project, SBT gives this error:

`The same directory is used for output for multiple projects`

So instead I copied the *App*, *Dao* and *Core* project definitions into the parent project definition. That is, declared all projects and their dependencies in the single build file of the parent project.

Now everything works fine.

*However*, I have many parent projects. Each parent project uses different versions of the *App* project and the *Dao* project. (DAO = Data Access Object -- e.g. database storage or file storage, varies from project to project.)

So I'd need to repeat the definitions of *App* and *Dao* in each parent project, to avoid the  `The same directory is used for output for multiple projects`
error. But the result would be lots of duplicated project build code!

How can I avoid this?

I have one idea: Perhaps I can create a module for e.g. the *Dao* project, with a `trait` that declares all *Dao*'s dependencies (on 3rd party libraries). Then there would be almost no duplicated code, only the dependency from *Dao* on *Core* would be repeated in each parent project.

What do you think?
Do you perhaps have some other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting project dependencies in a trait, and mixing it in on demand [is one of the options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334534/how-to-set-default-libs-for-sbt-subprojects/4335158#4335158).

However, I'd suggest you to look into [SBT 0.10](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki) (you will anyway will have to migrate to it one day). In a new SBT it can be done as easy as

```
import sbt._

object RootProject extends Build
{
        lazy val projects = Seq(root, core, dao, app)

        override val root = Project("root", file(".")) aggregate(core, dao, app)
        lazy val core  = Project("core", file("core"))
        lazy val app  = Project("app", file("app")) dependsOn(core)
        lazy val dao = Project("dao", file("dao")) dependsOn(core)
}
```

,where any project - `core`, `app`, `dao` - could be a standalone one with it's own settings and dependencies.

Comment: I didn't expect such a lovely solution! (I.e. SBT 0.10) Thanks. Here is a link to the SBT 0.10 docs on the `aggregate` and the `dependsOn` stuff: https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Full-Configuration