# Can someone explain the right way to use SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

*I'm getting out off the closet on this! I don't understand SBT. There, I said it, now help me please.*

All roads lead to Rome, and that is the same for SBT: To get started with `SBT` there is `SBT`, `SBT Launcher`, `SBT-extras`, etc, and then there are different ways to include and decide on repositories. **Is there a 'best' way?**

I'm asking because sometimes I get a little lost. The SBT documentation is very thorough and complete, but I find myself not knowing when to use `build.sbt` or `project/build.properties` or `project/Build.scala` or `project/plugins.sbt`.

Then it becomes fun, there is the `Scala-IDE` and `SBT` - *What is the correct way of using them together?* What comes first, the chicken or the egg?

**Most importantly is probably, how do you find the right repositories and versions to include in your project?** Do I just pull out a machette and start hacking my way forward? I quite often find projects that include everything and the kitchen sink, and then I realize - I'm not the only one who gets a little lost.

As a simple example, right now, I'm starting a brand new project. I want to use the latest features of `SLICK` and `Scala` and this will probably require the latest version of SBT. *What is the sane point to get started, and why?* In what file should I define it and how should it look? I know I can get this working, but I would really like an expert opinion on where everything should go (why it should go there will be a bonus).

I've been using `SBT` for small projects for well over a year now. I used `SBT` and then `SBT Extras` (as it made some headaches magically disappear), but I'm not sure why I should be using the one or the other. I'm just getting a little frustrated for not understanding how things fit together (`SBT` and repositories), and think it will save the next guy coming this way a lot of hardship if this could be explained in human terms.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "there is the Scala-IDE and SBT"? You define your project with sbt and sbt can generate an ide (eclipse oder intellij) project. So SBT comes first...

Comment: @Jan I mentioned that because Scala-IDE uses SBT as build manager. See http://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/wiki/SBT-based_build_manager and lower down in the post they mention "There is not need to define your SBT project file." which I found confusing.

Comment: ok. As i usually use intellij (or sublime) to edit scala I didn't know that. I guess the builder generates its own sbt configs?

Comment: In scala you should use for your project and all your library's the same major version. If you use ScalaIDE you can simply add a jar containing the library of your choice to your project. Make sure Your project and included library have already same version. No need for SBT so far.

Comment: @JacobusR The fact that the Scala IDE uses SBT to build your project's sources is an implementation detail, and users need *not* to worry about this. There are really 0 implications. Outside of Eclipse users can build a project with SBT, Maven, Ant, ..., and that won't make any difference for the Scala IDE. One more thing, even if you have a SBT project, the Scala IDE doesn't care, i.e., it doesn't look for your ``Build.scala`` to set up the classpath, and that's why you actually need [sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse) to generate the Eclipse .classpath. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your Problem seems to be the Eclipse Scala IDE, ot more precisely it's lack of documentation for the given use case. Isn't it?

Comment: @MircoDotta Fantastic, that was part of my concern. Thanks for explaining that.

Comment: @Jan Scala IDE added to the confusion, and yes, documentation that gives a bigger picture on setting up a good Scala development environment and some solid guidance of suitable programming workflows would come in very handy.

Comment: @JacobusR Great. And we are very keen in accepting [pull-requests for the doc](https://github.com/scala-ide/docs) ;-) The doc in Assembla is old and not mantained anymore (yes, we'll delete it soon, we just need to find some spare time), the new documentation is [here](http://scala-ide.org/docs/) and pull-requests goes [here](https://github.com/scala-ide/docs)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> *Most importantly is probably, how do you find the right repositories and versions to include in your project? Do I just pull out a machette and start hacking my way forward? I quite often find projects that include everything and the kitchen sink*

For Scala-based dependencies, I would go with what the authors recommend. For instance: http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/#SBT indicates to use:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "6.0.4"
```

Or https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/ has instructions on where to add:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.1.0-RC1")
```

For Java-based dependencies, I use http://mvnrepository.com/ to see what's out there, then click on the SBT tab. For instance http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.opencsv/opencsv/2.3 indicates to use:

```
libraryDependencies += "net.sf.opencsv" % "opencsv" % "2.3"
```

Then pull out the machette and start hacking your way forward. If you are lucky you don't end up using jars that depends on some of the same jars but with incompatible versions. Given the Java ecosystem, you often end up including everything and the kitchen sink and it takes some effort to eliminate dependencies or ensure you are not missing required dependencies.

> *As a simple example, right now, I'm starting a brand new project. I want to use the latest features of SLICK and Scala and this will probably require the latest version of SBT. What is the sane point to get started, and why?*

I think the sane point is to [build immunity to sbt gradually](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093779/quotes#qt0482733).

Make sure you understand:

1. scopes format `{<build-uri>}<project-id>/config:key(for task-key)`
2. the 3 flavors of settings (`SettingKey`, `TaskKey`, `InputKey`) - read the section called "Task Keys" in http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Basic-Def

Keep those 4 pages open at all times so that you can jump and look up various definitions and examples:

1. http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Basic-Def
2. http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/index
3. http://harrah.github.com/xsbt/latest/sxr/Keys.scala.html
4. http://harrah.github.com/xsbt/latest/sxr/Defaults.scala.html

Make maximum use of `show` and `inspect` *and the tab completion* to get familiar with actual values of settings, their dependencies, definitions and related settings. I don't believe the relationships you'll discover using `inspect` are documented anywhere. If there is a better way I want to know about it.

Answer (score 26):

The way I use sbt is:

1. Use [sbt-extras](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras) - just get the shell script and add it to the root of you project
2. Create a `project` folder with a `MyProject.scala` file for setting up sbt. I much prefer this over the `build.sbt` approach - it's scala and is more flexible
3. Create a `project/plugins.sbt` file and add the appropriate plugin for your IDE. Either sbt-eclipse, sbt-idea or ensime-sbt-cmd so that you can generate project files for eclipse, intellij or ensime.
4. Launch sbt in the root of your project and generate the project files for your IDE
5. Profit

I don't bother checking in the IDE project files since they are generated by sbt, but there may be reasons you want to do that.

You can see an example set up like this [here](https://github.com/fly-object-space/fly-scala).

Comment: Thank you for the good answer. I accepted the other answer, because it covers more ground, and up-voted your's cause it's really good also. I would have accepted both if I could.

Answer (score 0):

Use Typesafe Activator, a fancy way of calling sbt, which comes with project templates and seeds : https://typesafe.com/activator

```
Activator new

Fetching the latest list of templates...

Browse the list of templates: http://typesafe.com/activator/templates
Choose from these featured templates or enter a template name:
 1) minimal-java
 2) minimal-scala
 3) play-java
 4) play-scala
(hit tab to see a list of all templates)
```

Comment: I'm partial to the idea that, when in doubt, adding _more_ magic to the mix isn't likely to solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

### Installation

`brew install sbt` or similar installs sbt which technically speaking consists of

- sbt launcher script (bash script) https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package
- sbt launcher jar (sbt-launcher.jar) https://github.com/sbt/launcher
- core sbt (sbt.jar) https://github.com/sbt/sbt

When you execute `sbt` from terminal it actually runs the sbt launcher bash script. Personally, I never had to worry about this trinity, and just use sbt as if it was a single thing.

### Configuration

To configure sbt for a particular project save `.sbtopts` file at the root of the project. To configure sbt system-wide modify `/usr/local/etc/sbtopts`. Executing `sbt -help` should tell you the exact location. For example, to give sbt more memory as one-off execute `sbt -mem 4096`, or save `-mem 4096` in `.sbtopts` or `sbtopts` for memory increase to take effect permanently.

### Project structure

`sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8` creates a minimal Hello World sbt project structure

```
.
├── README.md  // most important part of any software project
├── build.sbt  // build definition of the project
├── project    // build definition of the build (sbt is recursive - explained below)
├── src        // test and main source code
└── target     // compiled classes, deployment package
```

### Frequent commands

```
test                                                // run all test
testOnly                                            // run only failed tests
testOnly -- -z "The Hello object should say hello"  // run one specific test
run                                                 // run default main
runMain example.Hello                               // run specific main
clean                                               // delete target/
package                                             // package skinny jar
assembly                                            // package fat jar
publishLocal                                        // library to local cache
release                                             // library to remote repository
reload                                              // after each change to build definition
```

### Myriad of shells

```
scala              // Scala REPL that executes Scala language (nothing to do with sbt)
sbt                // sbt REPL that executes special sbt shell language (not Scala REPL)
sbt console        // Scala REPL with dependencies loaded as per build.sbt
sbt consoleProject // Scala REPL with project definition and sbt loaded for exploration with plain Scala langauage
```

### Build definition is a proper Scala project

This is one of key idiomatic sbt concepts. I will try to explain with a question. Say you want to define a sbt task that will execute an HTTP request with scalaj-http. Intuitively we might try the following inside `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies +=  "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.4.2"

val fooTask = taskKey[Unit]("Fetch meaning of life")
fooTask := {
  import scalaj.http._ // error: cannot resolve symbol
  val response = Http("http://example.com").asString
  ...
}
```

However this will error saying missing `import scalaj.http._`. How is this possible when we, right above, added `scalaj-http` to `libraryDependencies`? Furthermore, why does it work when, instead, we add the dependency to `project/build.sbt`?

```
// project/build.sbt
libraryDependencies +=  "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.4.2"
```

The answer is that `fooTask` is actually part of a *separate Scala project* from your main project. This different Scala project can be found under `project/` directory which has its own `target/` directory where its compiled classes reside. In fact, under `project/target/config-classes` there should be a class that decompiles to something like

```
object $9c2192aea3f1db3c251d extends scala.AnyRef {
  lazy val fooTask : sbt.TaskKey[scala.Unit] = { /* compiled code */ }
  lazy val root : sbt.Project = { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

We see that `fooTask` is simply a member of a regular Scala object named `$9c2192aea3f1db3c251d`. Clearly `scalaj-http` should be a dependency of the project defining `$9c2192aea3f1db3c251d` and not the dependency of the proper project. Hence it needs to be declared in `project/build.sbt` instead of `build.sbt`, because `project` is where the build definition Scala project resides.

To drive the point that build definition is just another Scala project, execute `sbt consoleProject`. This will load Scala REPL with the build definition project on the classpath. You should see an import along the lines of

```
import $9c2192aea3f1db3c251d
```

So now we can interact directly with build definition project by calling it with Scala proper instead of `build.sbt` DSL. For example, the following executes `fooTask`

```
$9c2192aea3f1db3c251d.fooTask.eval
```

`build.sbt` under root project is a spcial DSL that helps define the build definition Scala project under `project/`.

And build definition Scala project, can have its own build definition Scala project under `project/project/` and so on. We say [sbt is recursive](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Organizing-Build.html#sbt+is+recursive).

### sbt is parallel by-default

sbt builds [DAG](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Task-Graph.html#Task+graph) out of tasks. This allows it to analyse dependencies between tasks and execute them in parallel and even perform deduplication. `build.sbt` DSL is designed with this in mind, which might lead to initially surprising semantics. What do you think the order of execution is in the following snippet?

```
def a = Def.task { println("a") }
def b = Def.task { println("b") }
lazy val c = taskKey[Unit]("sbt is parallel by-default")
c := {
  println("hello")
  a.value
  b.value
}
```

Intuitively one might think flow here is to first print `hello` then execute `a`, and then `b` task. However this actually means execute `a` and `b` in **parallel**, and **before** `println("hello")` so

```
a
b
hello
```

or because order of `a` and `b` is not guaranteed

```
b
a
hello
```

Perhaps paradoxically, in sbt it is easier to do parallel than serial. If you need serial ordering you will have to use special things like `Def.sequential` or `Def.taskDyn` to emulate *for-comprehension*.

```
def a = Def.task { println("a") }
def b = Def.task { println("b") }
lazy val c = taskKey[Unit]("")
c := Def.sequential(
  Def.task(println("hello")),
  a,
  b
).value
```

is similar to

```
for {
  h <- Future(println("hello"))
  a <- Future(println("a"))
  b <- Future(println("b"))
} yield ()
```

where we see there is no dependencies between components, whilst

```
def a = Def.task { println("a"); 1 }
def b(v: Int) = Def.task { println("b"); v + 40 }
def sum(x: Int, y: Int) = Def.task[Int] { println("sum"); x + y }
lazy val c = taskKey[Int]("")
c := (Def.taskDyn {
  val x = a.value
  val y = Def.task(b(x).value)
  Def.taskDyn(sum(x, y.value))
}).value
```

is similar to

```
def a = Future { println("a"); 1 }
def b(v: Int) = Future { println("b"); v + 40 }
def sum(x: Int, y: Int) = Future { x + y }

for {
  x <- a
  y <- b(x)
  c <- sum(x, y)
} yield { c }
```

where we see `sum` depends on and has to wait for `a` and `b`.

In other words

- for *applicative* semantics, use `.value`
- for *monadic* semantics use `sequential` or `taskDyn`

Consider [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61445196/5205022) semantically confusing snippet as a result of the dependency building nature of `value`, where instead of

```
`value` can only be used within a task or setting macro, such as :=, +=, ++=, Def.task, or Def.setting.
val x = version.value
                ^
```

we have to write

```
val x = settingKey[String]("")
x := version.value
```

Note the syntax `.value` is about relationships in the DAG and does not mean

> "give me the value right now"

instead it means something like

> "my caller depends on me first, and once I know how the whole DAG fits together, I will be able to provide my caller with the requested value"

So now it might be a bit clearer why `x` cannot be assigned a value yet; there is no value yet available in the relationship building stage.

We can clearly see a difference in semantics between Scala proper and the DSL language in `build.sbt`. Here are few rules of thumbs that work for me

- DAG is made out of expressions of type `Setting[T]`
- In most cases we simply use `.value` syntax and sbt will take care of establishing relationship between `Setting[T]`
- Occasionally we have to manually tweak a part of DAG and for that we use `Def.sequential` or `Def.taskDyn`
- Once these ordering/relationship syntatic oddities are taken care of, we can rely on the usual Scala semantics for building the rest of the business logic of tasks.

### Commands vs Tasks

Commands are a lazy way out of the DAG. Using commands it is easy to mutate the build state and serialise tasks as you wish. The cost is we loose parallelisation and deduplication of tasks provided by DAG, which way tasks should be the prefered choice. You can think of commands as a kind of permanent recording of a session one might do inside `sbt shell`. For example, given

```
vval x = settingKey[Int]("")
x := 13
lazy val f = taskKey[Int]("")
f := 1 + x.value
```

consider the output of the following session

```
sbt:root> x
[info] 13
sbt:root> show f
[info] 14
sbt:root> set x := 41
[info] Defining x
[info] The new value will be used by f
[info] Reapplying settings...
sbt:root> show f
[info] 42
```

In particular not how we mutate the build state with `set x := 41`. Commands enables us to make a permanent recording of the above session, for example

```
commands += Command.command("cmd") { state =>
  "x" :: "show f" :: "set x := 41" :: "show f" :: state
}
```

We can also make the command type-safe using `Project.extract` and `runTask`

```
commands += Command.command("cmd") { state =>
  val log = state.log
  import Project._
  log.info(x.value.toString)
  val (_, resultBefore) = extract(state).runTask(f, state)
  log.info(resultBefore.toString)
  val mutatedState = extract(state).appendWithSession(Seq(x := 41), state)
  val (_, resultAfter) = extract(mutatedState).runTask(f, mutatedState)
  log.info(resultAfter.toString)
  mutatedState
}
```

### Scopes

Scopes come into play when we try to answer the following kinds of questions

- How to define task once and make it available to all the sub-projects in multi-project build?
- How to avoid having test dependencies on the main classpath?

sbt has a multi-axis scoping space which can be navigated using [slash syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59868453/5205022), for example,

```
show  root   /  Compile         /  compile   /   scalacOptions
        |        |                  |             |
     project    configuration      task          key
```

Personally, I rarely find myself having to worry about scope. Sometimes I want to compile just test sources

```
Test/compile
```

or perhaps execute a particular task from a particular subproject without first having to navigate to that project with `project subprojB`

```
subprojB/Test/compile
```

I think the following rules of thumb help avoid scoping complications

- do not have multiple `build.sbt` files but only a single master one under root project that controls all other sub-projects
- share tasks via auto plugins
- factor out common settings into plain Scala `val` and explicitly add it to each sub-project

### Multi-project build

Iinstead of multiple build.sbt files for each subproject

```
.
├── README.md
├── build.sbt                  // OK
├── multi1
│   ├── build.sbt              // NOK
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── multi2
│   ├── build.sbt              // NOK
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── project                    // this is the meta-project
│   ├── FooPlugin.scala        // custom auto plugin
│   ├── build.properties       // version of sbt and hence Scala for meta-project
│   ├── build.sbt              // OK - this is actually for meta-project 
│   ├── plugins.sbt            // OK
│   ├── project
│   └── target
└── target
```

Have a single master `build.sbt` to rule them all

```
.
├── README.md
├── build.sbt                  // single build.sbt to rule theme all
├── common
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── multi1
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── multi2
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── project
│   ├── FooPlugin.scala
│   ├── build.properties
│   ├── build.sbt
│   ├── plugins.sbt
│   ├── project
│   └── target
└── target
```

There is a common practice of [factoring out common settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334534/how-to-set-default-dependencies-for-all-subprojects-in-sbt#comment31469407_20951900) in multi-project builds

> define a sequence of common settings in a val and add them to each
>   project. Less concepts to learn that way.

for example

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  scalacOptions := Seq(
    "-Xfatal-warnings",
    ...
  ),
  publishArtifact := true,
  ...
)

lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(settings)
  .aggregate(
    multi1,
    multi2
  )
lazy val multi1 = (project in file("multi1")).settings(commonSettings)
lazy val multi2 = (project in file("multi2")).settings(commonSettings)
```

Projects navigation

```
projects         // list all projects
project multi1   // change to particular project
```

### Plugins

Remember build definition is a proper Scala project that resides under `project/`. This is where we define a plugin by creating `.scala` files

```
.                          // directory of the (main) proper project
├── project
│   ├── FooPlugin.scala    // auto plugin
│   ├── build.properties   // version of sbt library and indirectly Scala used for the plugin
│   ├── build.sbt          // build definition of the plugin
│   ├── plugins.sbt        // these are plugins for the main (proper) project, not the meta project
│   ├── project            // the turtle supporting this turtle
│   └── target             // compiled binaries of the plugin
```

Here is a minimal [auto plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521226/how-to-share-sbt-plugin-configuration-between-multiple-projects/28522496#28522496) under `project/FooPlugin.scala`

```
object FooPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  object autoImport {
      val barTask = taskKey[Unit]("")
  }

  import autoImport._

  override def requires = plugins.JvmPlugin  // avoids having to call enablePlugin explicitly
  override def trigger = allRequirements

  override lazy val projectSettings = Seq(
    scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Xfatal-warnings"),
    barTask := { println("hello task") },
    commands += Command.command("cmd") { state =>
      """eval println("hello command")""" :: state
    }   
  )
}
```

The override

```
override def requires = plugins.JvmPlugin
```

should effectively enable the plugin for all sub-projects without having to call explicitly `enablePlugin` in `build.sbt`.

### IntelliJ and sbt

Please enable the following setting (which should really be enabled by [default](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-12850))

```
use sbt shell
```

under

```
Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | sbt | sbt projects
```

### Key references

- [sbt - A declarative DSL](https://jazzy.id.au/2015/03/04/sbt-declarative-dsl.html)
- [Task graph](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Task-Graph.html#Task+graph)
- [How to share sbt plugin configuration between multiple projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521226/how-to-share-sbt-plugin-configuration-between-multiple-projects/28522496#28522496)
- [Use sbt shell for build and import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49213653/use-sbt-shell-for-build-and-import/60706327#60706327)