# How to filter/disable a scalac option for all subprojects in SBT in a DRY way

Tags: scala, sbt

My project has multiple subprojects, and I use `sbt-tpolecat`[1](https://github.com/DavidGregory084/sbt-tpolecat) in this project.
I use a Java framework in my code. This framework use fluent interface heavily so I need to suppress many "discarded non-Unit value" warnings in my code.

This `sbt-tpolecat` provided a lot of useful scalac options out of the box, and I just want to exclude the `-Wvalue-discard` scalac option for my use case.

The problem is I have 4-5 subprojects[2](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html) in this project. And now I need to add the below to every subproject's `settings`:

```scala
sub_project_name.settings(
  scalacOptions ~= (_.filterNot(Set("-Wvalue-discard")))
)
// or
sub_project_name.settings(valueDiscardSetting)

lazy val valueDiscardSetting =
  Seq(scalacOptions ~= (_.filterNot(Set("-Wvalue-discard"))))
```

Is there a way to exclude this option in all subprojects in a DRY way?
My current subprojects hierarchy is similar to this:

```
App -> Frontend -> Common
    -> Backend  -> Common
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Common settings val

There is a common practice of [factoring out common settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334534/how-to-set-default-dependencies-for-all-subprojects-in-sbt#comment31469407_20951900) in multi-project builds

> define a sequence of common settings in a val and add them to each
>   project. Less concepts to learn that way.

for example

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  scalacOptions ~= (_.filterNot(Set("-Wvalue-discard"))),
  ...
)

lazy val util = (project in file("util")).settings(commonSettings)
lazy val core = (project in file("core")).settings(commonSettings)
```

### Common settings auto plugin

[Auto plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28522496/5205022) can set settings for every project. Create the following small plugin under `project/CommonSettingsPlugin.scala`

```
object CommonSettingsPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  override def requires = plugins.JvmPlugin
  override def trigger = allRequirements
  override lazy val projectSettings = Seq(
    scalacOptions ~= (_.filterNot(Set("-Wvalue-discard")))
  )
}
```

The override

```
override def requires = plugins.JvmPlugin
```

should effectively enable the plugin without having to call explicitly `enablePlugin` in `build.sbt`.

### Override settings with [`onLoad`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60393081/5205022)

`onLoad` happens at the end after all projects are built and loaded.

```
lazy val settingsAlreadyOverridden = SettingKey[Boolean]("settingsAlreadyOverridden","Has overrideSettings command already run?")
settingsAlreadyOverridden := false
commands += Command.command("removeScalacOptions") { state =>
  if (settingsAlreadyOverridden.value) {
    state
  } else {
    Project.extract(state).appendWithSession(
      Seq(
        settingsAlreadyOverridden := true,
        scalacOptions ~= (_.filterNot(Set("-Wvalue-discard")))
      ),
      state
    )
  }
}

onLoad in Global := (onLoad in Global).value andThen ("removeScalacOptions" :: _)
```

Also consider how they addressed the problem in community-build via [`removeScalacOptions`](https://github.com/lightbend/dbuild/issues/144#issuecomment-250267337).