# Use sbt shell for build and import

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

There is this option in IntelliJ. What does it do? When should we enable it and when not?

> [ ] Use sbt shell for build and import (requires sbt 0.13.5+)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

From [the youtrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10984):

> Currently in sbt projects, project settings are imported, but
>   compiling is done via the compiler providede by the Scala plugin. In
>   some sbt configurations that don't map well to the IDEA project model,
>   this will result in errors, forcing users to use the shell in addition
>   to the IDE.
>
> For a better integration, we want the Scala plugin to be controlling
>   an sbt shell or server (new functionality in sbt 1.0)