# Why value method cannot be used outside macros?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-macros

The error message

```
`value` can only be used within a task or setting macro, such as :=, +=, ++=, Def.task, or Def.setting.
val x = version.value
                ^
```

clearly indicates how to fix the problem, for example, using `:=`

```
val x = settingKey[String]("")
x := version.value
```

The explanation in [sbt uses macros heavily](https://jazzy.id.au/2015/03/04/sbt-declarative-dsl.html#sbt-uses-macros-heavily) states

> The `value` method itself is in fact a macro, one that if you invoke it
>   outside of the context of another macro, will result in a compile time
>   error, the exact error message being...
>   And you can see why, since sbt settings are entirely declarative, you
>   can’t access the value of a task from the key, it doesn’t make sense
>   to do that.

however I am confused what is meant by *declarative* nature of sbt being the reason. For example, intuitively I would think the following vanilla Scala snippet is semantically similar to sbt's

```
def version: String = ???
lazy val x = s"Hello $version"  // ok

trait Foo {
  def version: String
  val x = version               // ok
}
```

As this is legal, clearly the Scala snippet is not semantically equivalent to the sbt one. I was wondering if someone could elaborate on why `value` cannot be used outside macros? Is the reason purely syntactic related to macro syntax or am I missing something fundamental about sbt's nature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As another sentence there says

> Defining sbt’s task engine is done by giving sbt a series of settings, each setting declaring a task implementation. sbt then executes those settings in order. Tasks can be declared multiple times by multiple settings, the last one to execute wins.

So at the moment when the line

```
val x = version.value
```

would be executed (if it were allowed!), that whole program is still being set up and SBT doesn't know the final definition of `version`.

> In what sense is the program "still being set up"?

SBT's order of actions is, basically (maybe missing something):

1. All your Scala build code is run.
2. It contains some settings and tasks definitions, SBT collects those when it encounters (along with ones from core, plugins, etc.)
3. They are topologically sorted into the task graph, deduplicated ("the last one to execute wins"), etc.
4. Settings are evaluated.
5. Now you are allowed to actually run tasks (e.g. from SBT console).

`version.value` is only available after step 4, but `val x = version.value` runs on step 1.

> Would not lazy evaluation take care of that?

Well, when you write `val x = ...` there is no lazy evaluation. But `lazy val x = ...` runs on step 1 too.